# cordova throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError : FileTransfer' when function is called within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, cordova, file-transfer

So i am developing a cordova app which uses cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-file-transfer to download an image and then use it as profile picture is user has logged in. my index.js is :

```
//THIS IS CUSTOM LOG FUNCTION PLEASE IGNORE
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
(currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
currentdate.getFullYear() + " - " +
currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" +
currentdate.getSeconds();

function logit(x) {
    console.log(x);
    var oldlogs = localStorage.getItem("LOG");
    localStorage.setItem("LOG", oldlogs + "\n" + datetime + " >> " + x);
}
//CUSTOM LOG FUNCTION END
function downloadFile() {
logit("dp 1");
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); //this is index.js:37
var uri = encodeURI('http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-5.jpg');
var fileURL = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + MD5(promail) + ".png";
logit("dp 2");
fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL,
    function (entry) {
        logit("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        $('#proimg').attr('src', cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + MD5(promail) + ".png");
    },

    function (error) {
        logit("download error source " + error.source);
        logit("download error target " + error.target);
        logit("download error code" + error.code);
    },

    false, {}
);
}
var login = localStorage.getItem("login");
if (login != "true") {
logit("no login detcted");
document.getElementById("profile-box").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("login-box").style.display = "block";
} else {
var proname = localStorage.getItem("name");
var promail = localStorage.getItem("email");
logit("Logged in already");
document.getElementById("profile-box").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("login-box").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("proname").innerHTML = proname;
document.getElementById("promail").innerHTML = promail;
var proimgsrc = document.getElementById("proimg").getAttribute('src');
$(document).ready(function () {
    downloadFile(); //this is index.js:74
});
}
```

while using phonegap serve, console throws error;

```
Logged in already
dp 1
Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined
at downloadFile           (index.js:37)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>          (index.js:74)
at j           (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]           (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ready           (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.I           (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
```

but i believe there is no systax error because the code works when i click on button with id="download";

```
<li><a class="btn-floating green" id="download"><i class="material-icons">download</i></a></li>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#download").click(function() {
        downloadFile();
    });
</script>
```

when i click on download the console says:

```
 dp 1  
 dp 2
download error source   http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-5.jpg
download error target null2a7844139ea9422d59a6beac69adebe1.png download 
error code1
```

which is completly fine because browser do not recognize cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, the download link also works when testing on real device and it downloads the image fine.
maybe some deviceready problem?
edit 1: i have included index.js in index.html